# Pyramid ignoring csrf validation for certain views

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

I'm looking for something like Django's `csrf_ignore` decorator.

I have defined my csrf validation in the usual way, via subscriber:

```
@subscriber(NewRequest)
def csrf_validation(event):
    ...
```

Then I have another view which accepts POST images for upload:

```
@view_config(route_name="upload_images", request_method="POST", renderer="json")
def upload_images(request):
    ...
```

But how do I ignore csrf validation for the `upload_images` view? I'm using Pyramid 1.3, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyramid 1.4 comes with support for a `check_csrf` predicate on `view_config` itself. Before that, you would have to implement your own custom predicate that does the checking and apply it to your views.

A `NewRequest` subscriber happens very early in the request pipeline and many properties are not available to you at this point. For example, it has not yet computed which route matches. Thus you can only really do `if not request.path_info.startswith('/upload_image_path'):`.

You could defer your check until a `ContextFound` subscriber, in which case you could check `if request.matched_route.name ~= 'upload_images'`.

Your best option, however, is to apply the csrf check to individual views explicitly, and this can be done using a custom predicate.

```py
def csrf_check(context, request):
    # do check, return True if passes, or raise some exception if fails

@view_config(..., custom_predicates=[csrf_check])
def not_upload_images(request):
    # ....
```

Comment: I think I'd go with the best option, might be tedious to repeat the custom_predicates on every view but explicit is better than implicit. Thanks!